# Final for function parameter optimization

Tags: java, jvm

Is there any noticeable optimization made by JVM when I add final to parameter in Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: no. Longer answer: nope.

Comment: Slightly longer answer as to why can be found here: [The Final Word On the final Keyword](http://renaud.waldura.com/doc/java/final-keyword.shtml#methods).

Answer (score 1):

It only helps you to make sure that you are not changing the reference to the objects passed through the parameters .. but with regards to the JVM, it does not make any difference

Answer (score 1):

It might not have a performance uptick for the variables, but it will have a performance uptick for making methods final, as it increases the likelihood the JVM will inline/JIT the method.